# linking font with the style.css when when the font is in a different folder

Tags: html, css

so im having trouble linking my font (that i prefer to keep in a separate folder since its from the internet) from my css stuff. I was able to successfully link the font when i put it in the same folder as my style.css. i would like to keep my files separate like this:

Project4Root
↳index.html
  ↳css(folder) -> style.css, ↳fonts(folder) ->TESLA.tff

or

Project4Root
  ↳index.html
  ↳css (folder)
    ->style.css
  ↳fonts(folder)
    ->TESLA.tff

---

in the style.css when i use @font-face, how would i write the url for either? i dont know how the url would be.

`@font-face { font-family: "Tesla"; src: url(WHAT DO I PUT HERE);}`

the only other way i can think of that I can do to use this font is to create a separate style.css in the font folder and then link that to the html. any help would be appreciated. My apologies if this a silly question.

Comment: @font-face { font-family: "Tesla"; src: url(fonts/TESLA.tff);} should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Tesla"; src: url( '../fonts/TESLA.ttf' );
}
```

That `../` is equal to go up one level, and it's equal to going back in your GUI. I hope I understand your question right.